# What is the difference between submit and execute method with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

I found there are two ways (submit and execute) to add a Runnable into a thread pool, what is the difference?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The difference is that `execute` doesn't return a `Future`, so you can't wait for the completion of the `Runnable` and get any exception it throws using that.

Comment: `Future` also allows you to get exceptions thrown by `Runnable`.

Comment: @axtavt: True, guess I should mention that too.

Comment: Also good to note that as a consequence of the exception being part of the Future's return value, the thread's uncaught exception handler will never be called for `submit`, whereas it will for `execute`.

Answer (score 16):

The `submit(...)` method is an executor framework extension introduced in `ExecutorService` interface.

Its main difference from `execute(Runnable)` is that `submit(...)` can accept a `Callable<V>` (whereas `execute()` accepts only `Runnable`) and returns an instance of `Future<V>`, which you can use later in the caller to retrieve the result asynchronously (potentially blocking until the computation performed by the `Callable` is completed).

Answer (score 1):

Submit appears to be a more generic form of execute. In particular, submit returns a Future object that represents the result of the computation.

[ThreadPoolExecutor-1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)

[ThreadPoolExecutor -2](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable)