# Catching thread exceptions from Java ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I'm working on a software development framework for parallel computing [JavaSeis.org](http://javaseis.org). I need a robust mechanism for reporting thread exceptions. During development, knowing where exceptions came from has high value, so I would like to err on the side of over-reporting. I would also like to be able to handle Junit4 testing in threads as well. Is the approach below reasonable or is there a better way ?

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class TestThreadFailure {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 1;
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);
    ThreadFailTask worker = new ThreadFailTask();
    Future<Integer> result = exec.submit(worker);
    try {
      Integer value = result.get();
      System.out.println("Result: " + value);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      System.out.println("Caught failure: " + t.toString());
      exec.shutdownNow();
      System.out.println("Stack Trace:");
      t.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Did not catch failure !!");
  }

  public static class ThreadFailTask implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer call() {
      int nbuf = 65536;
      double[][] buf = new double[nbuf][nbuf];
      return new Integer((int) buf[0][0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Similar: [Handling exceptions from Java ExecutorService tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe there is a standard 'hook' to get to these exceptions when using `submit()`. However, if you need to support `submit()` (which sounds reasonable, given that you use a `Callable`), you can always wrap the Callables and Runnables :

```
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 10, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>()) {
    @Override
    public <T> Future<T> submit(final Callable<T> task) {
        Callable<T> wrappedTask = new Callable<T>() {
            @Override
            public T call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    return task.call();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Oh boy, something broke!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        };

        return super.submit(wrappedTask);
    }
};
```

Of course, this method only works if you're the one building the `ExecutorService` in the first place. Furthermore, remember to override all three `submit()` variants.

Comment: Nice trick. Based on your example, and the notes from Greg above, I think I now have what I need.

Answer (score 27):

Consider calling [`execute()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) instead of [`submit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) on the [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). A [`Thread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) invoked with `execute()` will invoke the [`Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) when it fails.

Simply make a [`ThreadFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) that installs a `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` on all `Threads` and then invoke your work with `execute()` on the `ExecutorService` instead of `submit()`.

Have a look at this [related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929342).

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the related question ! I hadn't realized that submit() delegates the exception to Future.get(). Looking back over the results from my test program above, I now see the chain. I need the Future result, though ...

Comment: Well, if you need the future, then you've got to wrap it as in the accepted answer. I figured out the submit/execute thing when I installed an UncaughtExceptionHandler that wasn't being called. I was ignoring the result of submit, so changing to execute was a good solution.

Comment: Note that if your `ExecutorService` is actually a `ScheduledExecutorService` then the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` doesn't get invoked any more, even if you call `execute()`.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in this thread [What is the difference between submit and execute method with ThreadPoolExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016091/what-is-the-difference-between-submit-and-execute-method-with-threadpoolexecutor), using execute will only work if you implement Runnable and not Callable as execute cannot return a Future.

I think in your scenario you should build the future object so that it can accommodate the exception stuff also. So in case of exception you build the error message object.

Comment: Thanks, Fazal. That's my plan. I'm using an extension of Future to hold a variety of runtime stats, including exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

My original question asked how to implement "robust" thread exception handling with Java ExecutorService. Thanks to Angelo and Greg for pointers on how exception handling works with ExecutorService.submit() and Future.get(). My revised code fragment is shown below. The key point I learned here is that Future.get() catches all exceptions. If the the thread was interrupted or cancelled, you get the appropriate exception, otherwise, the exception is wrapped and re-thrown as an ExecutionException.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class TestThreadFailure {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 1;
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(size);
    ThreadFailTask worker = new ThreadFailTask();
    Future result = exec.submit(worker);
    try {
      Integer value = result.get();
      System.out.println("Result: " + value);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
      System.out.println("Caught failure: " + ex.toString());
      exec.shutdownNow();
      return;
    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
      System.out.println("Thread interrupted: " + iex.toString());
    } catch (CancellationException cex) {
      System.out.println("Thread cancelled: " + cex.toString());
    }
    exec.shutdownNow();
    throw new RuntimeException("Did not catch failure !!");
  }

  public static class ThreadFailTask implements Callable {
    @Override
    public Integer call() {
      int nbuf = 65536;
      double[][] buf = new double[nbuf][nbuf];
      return new Integer((int) buf[0][0]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a great deal of luck with other answers because I needed the actual exception instance, itself, not just a printed stack trace. For me, the accepted answer involving [ThreadPoolExecutor#afterExecute()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute%28java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) of the question "[Why is UncaughtExceptionHandler not called by ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838923/why-is-uncaughtexceptionhandler-not-called-by-executorservice)" worked.

See the following sample code:

```
List<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i) {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    };

    tasks.add(task);
}

Optional<Throwable> opEmpty = Optional.empty();
/*
 * Use AtomicReference as a means of capturing the first thrown exception, since a
 * spawned thread can't "throw" an exception to the parent thread.
 */
final AtomicReference<Optional<Throwable>> firstThrownException =
        new AtomicReference<>(opEmpty);

/*
 * Use new ThreadPoolExecutor instead of Executors.newFixedThreadPool() so
 * that I can override afterExecute() for the purposes of throwing an
 * exception from the test thread if a child thread fails.
 */
ExecutorService execSvc = new ThreadPoolExecutor(numThreads, numThreads,
            0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()) {
    @Override
    public void afterExecute(Runnable task, Throwable failureCause) {
        if(failureCause == null) {
            // The Runnable completed successfully.
            return;
        }
        // only sets the first exception because it will only be empty on the first call.
        firstThrownException.compareAndSet(Optional.<Throwable>empty(), Optional.of(failureCause));
    }
};

for (Runnable task : tasks) {
    execSvc.execute(task);
}
execSvc.shutdown();
execSvc.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);

assertEquals(firstThrownException.get(), Optional.empty());
```

Answer (score 0):

To Handling exceptions in **ExecutorService** you have to take the advantage of **Callable** and **Future**.

**Callable** is similar to **Runnable** and both are functional interface but **run()** of Runnable doesn't throws exception and the return type is void where as **call()** of Callable returns a generics and throws exception.

Java-8 way:

```
ExecuterService executor = null; 
Future<Integer> future = null;

Callable<Integer> yourTask = () -> {
    //your implementation here();
    //your implementation here();
};

try 
   {
        executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        future = executor.submit(yourTask );
        Integer result = future.get();
        System.out.println(result);
   }
   catch (ExecutionException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) 
   {
    // TODO: handle exception
   }
   finally 
   {
       executer.shutdown();
   }
```

Comment: Down vote is welcome but please add a comment; it will be a learning for me.