# Catch and throw custom Exception from Java ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, threadpoolexecutor

I have a function that goes through a list of HappyObjects and sets their fields asynchronously. In the Callable, a JsonProcessingException can occur. I have to wrap this and other exceptions from this function into a custom exception (ControllerException) and throw that instead.

[Other Stack Overflow posts seem to suggest collect into a List of Futures and use get() to catch the exceptions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554549/handling-exceptions-for-threadpoolexecutor) Thus, this is what I have so far:

```
default List<HappyObj> fillfunction(final List<HappyObj> happyObjs) throws ControllerException {
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    List<Future<HappyObj>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (HappyObj happyObj : happyObjs) {
      Future<HappyObj> future = executor.submit(
          () -> {
            final List<Mood> moods = getMoods();

            for (Mood mood : moods) {
              final String json = getJsonEmotion();

              ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
              mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

              List<Emotion> emotions =
                  mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Emotion>>() {}); //JsonProcessingException can occur here

              MoodMetadata metadata = mood.getMoodMetadata();
              if (metadata != null && metadata.getEmotionMetadata() != null) {
                metadata.getEmotionMetadata().setEmotions(emotions);
              }
            }
            happyObj.setMoods(moods);
            return happyObj;
          });
      futures.add(future);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    final long maxSlaSec = 1;
    try {
      executor.awaitTermination(maxSlaSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      List<HappyObj> happyResult = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Future<HappyObj> future : futures) {
        happyResult.add(future.get());
      }
      return happyResult;
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      executor.shutdownNow();
      throw new ControllerException(e);
    }
  }
```

Is there a more elegant way than iterating through `List<Future>` and calling get on each to catch ExecutorException? I thought about using [execute() vs. submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492273/catching-thread-exceptions-from-java-executorservice), but then I can't handle the JsonProcessingException. I saw another post suggesting creating a ThreadPoolExecutor subclass and override the afterExecute(), but I wasn't able to handle the JsonProcessingException.

One of the reasons I asked this question is because since this method consists mainly of setters, the function was originally manipulating the given objects and returning void.

Comment: There is an `exceptionally` method after submitting task into an executor service. See if it solves the problem. And you could use an `AtomicReference` object to store your custom exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs of `ExecutionException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) (and also [the docs of `Future#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get--)), it already has wrapped that information. That is, you can use its `getCause` to inspect the `Exception` thrown by the `Callable`'s body.

Notice that `Callable#call` itself throws an `Exception`... When you throw an `Exception` from the `Callable`, it will be wrapped into an `ExecutionException` which will be thrown from the `Future#get` method, **for each `Callable`**, meaning that you can change your loop to catch an `ExecutionException` *for each `Future`* and inspect its `getCause`!

So you don't actually need to wrap it to a custom `ControllerException`.

The `Callable`s you create, can still return `null` of type `Void` for example, without needing to do anything about them.

Unless the scenario changes, then you don't need to extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` in this case. You don't even have to cast to `ThreadPoolExecutor`, because the `ExecutorService` interface already has the `submit`s you need. Just throw whatever `Exception` you need from the `Callable` (such as `JsonProcessingException` that you mentioned) when something goes wrong in the `Callable`, and then inspect the `ExecutionException` from each `Future#get` method to tell if an `JsonProcessingException` was thrown (and you can also determine in *which* one it was thrown, if you need).

> Is there a more elegant way than iterating through List and calling get on each to catch ExecutorException?

In my opinion, no, there is not, because you want to submit all `Callable`s first, then let them run in parallel, and at the end inspect their `ExecutionException` for any `Exception` thrown by the `Callable`s' body for each `Callable` (via `Future#get` of the returned `Future` by `submit`).

Comment: The Callables you create, can still return null of type Void for example, without needing to do anything about them: Thanks for this tidbit!

Comment: No problem. If it was not clear, I meant that you don't necessarily have to return something useful from the `Callable`. But you need it to be `Callable` and not a simple `Runnable` because of the `Exception` that can be thrown. You may also do it with a `Runnable` and store the `Exception`s somewhere instead of throwing them, but this would be a slightly more bloated code in my opinion.